# What is the difference between these two simplexml_load_file submissions PHP?

Tags: php, string, file, oauth

One is working (the string url), and the other is giving me a invalid signature failure in Oauth.

```
$whaturl=$endpoint.'?'.$link_string.'&oauth_signature='.$signature;
$newVenueXML = simplexml_load_file($whaturl) or die ("Error: Cannot create object");
```

and

```
$newVenueXML = simplexml_load_file('http://api.eventful.com/rest/venues/new?address=1101%20Grand%20Ave&app_key=my_app_key&city=Grand%20Lake&country=United%20States&name=Sagebrush%20Barbecue%20and%20Grill&oauth_consumer_key=my_consumer_key&oauth_nonce=718522065&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1474394973&oauth_token=my_token&oauth_version=1.0&postal_code=80447&region=Colorado&oauth_signature=nfOiJ1R7X%2Bw4d9I%2FY4duZ62TeFw%3D') or die ("Error: Cannot create object");
```

Where the components are all the same (i.e. the string is identical as far as I can tell using https://text-compare.com/). I must be missing something, because using the variable isn't working and the pure string is.

When I paste the $whaturl in the browser, I get the correct response.

Now, when I copy and paste the address bar from a correct submission, and then compare the two strings ($whaturl and the URL from the copy/paste of the address bar, $whaturl2), I see a difference when I echo the two variables where the &region= gets turned into ®ion= Is it possible that this same translation is taking place within the simplexml_load_file and therefore invalidating my $signature?

If so, any suggestions on how to handle this as I have escaped the &?

Comment: And `$signature` is really equal to `nfOiJ1R7X%2Bw4d9I%2FY4duZ62TeFw%3D`?

Comment: The signature is correct in all instances of testing (i.e. the variable $signature contains the actual signature).

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by using the http_build_query method and the `&amp;` as the $arg_seperator.